# Syntax error while using the MySQL query in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a CodeIgniter query.

```
if($this->session->userdata['login_session']['access_role']==5){
   $or_where="tbl_bankdata.b_filestatus=1 AND tbl_payment_invoice.payment_invoice IS NULL OR tbl_payment_invoice.payment_invoice = '' OR tbl_payment_invoice.payment_invoice =2 AND createby='".$this->session->userdata['login_session']['id']."'"; 
}
else{
    $or_where="tbl_bankdata.b_filestatus=1 AND tbl_payment_invoice.payment_invoice IS NULL OR tbl_payment_invoice.payment_invoice = '' OR tbl_payment_invoice.payment_invoice =2";
}

    $result = $this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('tbl_lead')
                    ->join('tbl_bankdata','tbl_lead.c_id=tbl_bankdata.lead_id','LEFT')
                    ->join('tbl_bankname','tbl_bankname.b_id=tbl_bankdata.b_bankname')
                    ->join('tbl_payment_invoice','tbl_bankname.b_id=tbl_payment_invoice.bank_id','LEFT')
                    ->where($or_where)
                    ->order_by('tbl_lead.date_of_created','DESC')
                    ->get()
                    ->result();
```

I have a MySQL query. (This MySQL query will display the last record of all the users from `tbl_payment_invoice` table)

```
SELECT A.* FROM tbl_payment_invoice A INNER JOIN (SELECT bank_id,MAX(payment_invoice_date) AS maxdt FROM tbl_payment_invoice GROUP BY bank_id) B ON A.`bank_id`=B.`bank_id` AND A.`payment_invoice_date`=B.`maxdt`
```

Now what I am doing is, I have to use MySQL query in this line                 `->join('tbl_payment_invoice','tbl_bankname.b_id=tbl_payment_invoice.bank_id','LEFT')`

Or I have to display all the records from the above table and the last record of all the users from the `tbl_payment_invoice` table using the above Codeigniter query.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: try to add `where($or_where)` before join

Comment: @FiodorovAndrei, Are you sure where condition will come before join?

Comment: see this [example](https://www.shakzee.com/how-to-use-joins-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: @FiodorovAndrei. give me some time to check

Comment: @FiodorovAndrei, I added where($or_where) before join. I am getting the same issue. I don't think so where the condition is the issue.

Comment: You don't have where in sql example. Try to ad in `where('1 = 1')`

Comment: tbl_red in  ->join('tbl_bankdata','tbl_red.c_id=tbl_bankdata.lead_id','LEFT')

Is that right ? or should it be tbl_reg

Comment: @IndraKumarS, thanks for the notice. That was a typo mistake. I updated.

Comment: @FiodorovAndrei, any more help in this?